Error list object has no attribute split only in Cloud interpreter VSCode runs the code right when accepting a string as input
I am building a function to split an input string into two lists as they are numbers, and find an intersection between both. My code runs fine in VSCode(Desktop) Python 3.12, no errors, but when I tried to run it on a Cloud(Coderbytes), returns an error saying the input is a list, and hence it has no split attribute ... Really confusing
def FindIntersection(strArr):
    # Split the input string using '"' and extract the lists
    strArr = strArr.split('"')

    
    # The lists are at indices 1 and 3 after splitting by '"'
    first = strArr[1]
    second = strArr[3]
    
    # Convert the strings to lists of integers
    One = [int(x) for x in first.strip("[] ").split(", ")]
    Two = [int(x) for x in second.strip("[] ").split(", ")]
    
    # Find the intersection using set intersection
    intersection = list(set(One).intersection(Two))
    
    # Create a comma-separated string from the intersection

    strArr = ", ".join(map(str, intersection))
    
    # Return the result
    return strArr

# Keep this function call here
print(FindIntersection(input()))

If I enter this string as input
["1, 3, 4, 7, 13", "1, 2, 4, 13, 15"]
The Output is: 1,4,13
and is fine in VSCode desktop version, but in
Coderbytes Cloud interpreter it gets the error
*
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/glot/main.py", line 23, in 
print(FindIntersection(["1, 3, 4, 7, 13", "1, 2, 4, 13, 15"]))
File "/home/glot/main.py", line 3, in FindIntersection
strArr = strArr.split('"')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'*
So my question is why Coderbytes recognizes the string as a list?
While VSCode validates it?

Now I have another problem ... if I input  ["1, 3, 9, 10, 17, 18", "1, 4, 9, 10"]

Your code is correct. It seems, in Coderbytes, the input is being pre-processed or interpreted differently. It's likely converting your input string ["1, 3, 4, 7, 13", "1, 2, 4, 13, 15"] directly into a list before passing it to your function. For enhanced clarity and user experience, it would be beneficial for Coderbytes to explicitly detail how input is handled internally in their environment before users attempt to code within the instructions section, if this information is not already provided.
Here's my updated code using list comprehension for clarity, assuming Coderbytes handles input as mentioned above.
def FindIntersection(strArr):
   # Assuming the input list contents are surrounded with extra quotes
   strArr2 = [item.strip('"') for item in strArr]

   # Convert the list of two strings to two different list of integers
   One = [int(x) for x in strArr2[0].split(", ")]
   Two = [int(x) for x in strArr2[1].split(", ")]

   # Find the intersection using set intersection
   intersection = list(set(One).intersection(Two))

   # Create a comma-separated string from the intersection
   strArr = ", ".join(map(str, intersection))

   # Return the result
   return strArr

# Keep this function call here
print(FindIntersection(input()))


Coderbyte seems to be pre-processing the input you provided before passing it to the code.
So, it is taking ["1, 3, 4, 7, 13", "1, 2, 4, 13, 15"] as list instead of a string (in VS-Code).
Here is the updated code: I have removed "Split the input string" part.
def FindIntersection(strArr):
    # The lists are at indices 1 and 3 after splitting by '"'
    first = strArr[0]
    second = strArr[1]
    
    # Convert the strings to lists of integers
    One = [int(x) for x in first.strip("[] ").split(", ")]
    Two = [int(x) for x in second.strip("[] ").split(", ")]
    
    # Find the intersection using set intersection
    intersection = list(set(One).intersection(Two))
    
    # Create a comma-separated string from the intersection
    strArr = ", ".join(map(str, intersection))
    
    # Return the result
    return strArr
# Keep this function call here
print(FindIntersection(input()))



This works fine! Thanks, didn't know I could simply remove the split method and it will work, I thought I had to remove the delimeter to create both lists.

Your code is fine. Maybe coderbytes interpreter takes inputs as sys.argv so they are taken in whatever format you pass instead of string.

So how can I fix it? So it's ok for them?

pass the input like this: "['1, 3, 4, 7, 13', '1, 2, 4, 13, 15']". I hope this works.
